# Define bijection in Agda

Tags: boolean, agda, bijection

The question is how do we define bijection in agda?
definition:

> We know that
>
> ```
> 2 + 2 = 2 × 2 = 2^2 = 4
> ```
>
> for numbers. Similarly, we have that
>
> ```
> Bool + Bool ∼= Bool × Bool ∼= Bool → Bool
> ```
>
> where A ∼= B means that there is a bijection between A and B, that is,
>   that there are `f : A → B` and `g : B → A` which are inverses of each
>   other, that is, `g (f x) = x` for all `x : A` and `f (g y) = y` for
>   all `y : B`.
>
> Implement these bijections in Agda!

So i started by defining `Bool` and some functions for it:

```
data Bool : Set where
  true  : Bool
  false : Bool

not : Bool → Bool
not true  = false
not false = true

T : Bool → Set
T true  = ⊤
T false = ⊥

_∧_ : Bool → Bool → Bool
true  ∧ b = b
false ∧ b = false

_∨_ : Bool → Bool → Bool
true  ∨ b = true
false ∨ b = b

_xor_ : Bool → Bool → Bool
true  xor b = not b
false xor b = b
```

But im stuck on the bijections, not sure at all how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The text of your exam also says what a bijection should be.

> there are `f : A → B` and `g : B → A` which are inverses of each other,
>   that is, `g (f x) = x` for all `x : A` and `f (g y) = y` for all `y : B`

In Agda you can define a record to package all that up:

```
record Bijection (A B : Set) : Set where
  field
    to : A -> B
    from : B -> A
    from-to : (x : A) -> from (to x) ≡ x
    to-from : (y : B) -> to (from y) ≡ y
```

The actual bijections you are supposed to implement yourself.